# Tree of all dependencies in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, parsing, text

I have to maintain an old project without documentation, and there is a database with a lot of tables and functions and stored procedures. I want to build a tree of dependencies between tables and stored procedures, for example, this procedure execs these procedures and uses these tables.

1. Is there any tool that can help me
2. If there is not, what is the start point for such algorithms? I mean that I can get source code of all procedures from database, and than parse it for all 'exec #', 'update #', 'insert into #' and so on. And in this case, what is the best way to solve this problem (regex maybe, or some special algorithms...)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are paid tools like redgate but if you want, you can always right click an object and select "view dependencies".

Comment: View Dependencies looks great. And know I google that I can get this from sys.sql_dependencies and create my own tool with "amazing" GUI, just for fun. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 23):

Higarian, your code was very useful to me.  I refined it a bit to remove circular dependencies, include table references, and to sort by the ObjectPath.

```
;with ObjectHierarchy ( Base_Object_Id , Base_Cchema_Id , Base_Object_Name , Base_Object_Type, object_id , Schema_Id , Name , Type_Desc , Level , Obj_Path) 
as 
    ( select  so.object_id as Base_Object_Id 
        , so.schema_id as Base_Cchema_Id 
        , so.name as Base_Object_Name 
        , so.type_desc as Base_Object_Type
        , so.object_id as object_id 
        , so.schema_id as Schema_Id 
        , so.name 
        , so.type_desc 
        , 0 as Level 
        , convert ( nvarchar ( 1000 ) , N'/' + so.name ) as Obj_Path 
    from sys.objects so 
        left join sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed on ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
        left join sys.objects rso on rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
    where rso.type is null 
        and so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF' ) 

    union all 
    select   cp.Base_Object_Id as Base_Object_Id 
        , cp.Base_Cchema_Id 
        , cp.Base_Object_Name 
        , cp.Base_Object_Type
        , so.object_id as object_id 
        , so.schema_id as ID_Schema 
        , so.name 
        , so.type_desc 
        , Level + 1 as Level 
        , convert ( nvarchar ( 1000 ) , cp.Obj_Path + N'/' + so.name ) as Obj_Path 
    from sys.objects so 
        inner join sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed on ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
        inner join sys.objects rso on rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
        inner join ObjectHierarchy as cp on rso.object_id = cp.object_id and rso.object_id <> so.object_id 
    where so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U') 
        and ( rso.type is null or rso.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U' ) ) 
        and cp.Obj_Path not like '%/' + so.name + '/%' )   -- prevent cycles n hierarcy
select   Base_Object_Name 
    , Base_Object_Type
    , REPLICATE ( '   ' , Level ) + Name as Indented_Name 
    , SCHEMA_NAME ( Schema_Id ) + '.' + Name as object_id 
    , Type_Desc as Object_Type 
    , Level 
    , Obj_Path 
from ObjectHierarchy as p 
order by Obj_Path
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Is it possible to have this check the dependencies of triggers too?

Comment: Should be a matter of changing      where so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U') 
     and ( rso.type is null or rso.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U' ) )     to      where so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U', 'TR') 
     and ( rso.type is null or rso.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U', 'TR' ) )

Answer (score 8):

Here,  The max(level) should solve your problem without needing external tools

```
;WITH   cte ( [ID] ,IDSchema,Nome,Tipo,level, SortCol)
AS     (SELECT [so].[object_id] AS ID
               ,so.[schema_id],so.[name],so.[type]
               ,0 AS [Level]     
               ,CAST ([so].[object_id] AS VARBINARY (MAX)) AS SortCol
          FROM [sys].[objects] so
            LEFT JOIN  sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed ON [ed].[referenced_id]=[so].[object_id]
            LEFT JOIN [sys].[objects] rso ON rso.[object_id]=[ed].referencing_id
            --in my database, if i insert tables on the search, it gets more tham 100 levels of recursivity, and that is bad
        WHERE [rso].[type]  IS NULL AND [so].[type] IN ('V','IF','FN','TF','P')

        UNION ALL
        SELECT [so].[object_id] AS ID
            ,so.[schema_id],so.[name],so.[type]
               ,Level + 1
               ,CAST (SortCol + CAST ([so].[object_id] AS BINARY (4)) AS VARBINARY (MAX))
        FROM   [sys].[objects] so
               INNER JOIN  sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed ON [ed].[referenced_id]=[so].[object_id]
               INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] rso ON rso.[object_id]=[ed].referencing_id
               INNER JOIN cte AS cp ON rso.[object_id] = [cp].[ID]
            WHERE [so].[type] IN ('V','IF','FN','TF','P')
            AND  ([rso].[type] IS NULL OR  [rso].[type]  IN ('V','IF','FN','TF','P'))
            )

--CTE
SELECT  ID, IDSchema,
    REPLICATE('   ',level)+nome AS Nome,'['+SCHEMA_NAME(IDSchema)+'].['+nome+']' AS Object,Tipo,Level,SortCol
FROM     cte AS p
ORDER BY  sortcol
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities as shown below to get all dependencies of any object

`SELECT
    *
FROM
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.myStoredProcedure', 'OBJECT')`

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned Redgate's paid add-ons.  ApexSQL is another company that makes add-ons for SQL Server.  Some of them cost money, but others are free and still pretty useful.

**ApexSQL Search** is one of the free ones.  It's 2 main features are:

1. Allows you to search a database's data or structure for certain text.
2. Can build a graphical tree of dependencies for one or more objects (what you want).

After you install it, just right-click an object or database and click `View dependencies` (near the bottom, with an icon next to it). Don't confuse it for `View Dependencies` (near the top, without an icon next to it), which is the one built into SQL Server.  I find the hierarchical diagram layout to be the most useful.

**Links:**

- [Product page with a good video demo](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx)
- [Article about the dependency mapping feature](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-visualize-sql-database-objects-dependencies/)
- [Download page](https://www.apexsql.com/Download.aspx)

Comment: Was quite excited to try this, but it seems the dependency viewer feature is now discontinued since July 2018 versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, they've moved these features into a non-free tool, [ApexSQL Analyze](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-analyze.aspx).