# Showing dependencies in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in process of creating table which would showing the dependencies of each view. With the help of a previous post ([Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10652746/tree-of-all-dependencies-in-a-sql-server-database)) and some adjusting of the logic I am now able to have a query which shows all the views and the table each of them pull on. One great aspect of the query is if a view pulls on another view it will show how this view is created and level it as expected. One enhancement I would like to implement is when a view is pulling from a table to include the stored procedure which populates that table. I am able to do this manually but would love to include it in the level system built into the query but unsure how. Any ideas if this would be possible.

How Query currently returns info:
[image: Current]

What i would like to implement:

[image: Enchancement]

```
--Below logic will list all views and what tables a view pulls from 
;with ObjectHierarchy ( Base_Object_Id , Base_Cchema_Id , Base_Object_Name , Base_Object_Type, object_id , Schema_Id , Name , Type_Desc , Level , Obj_Path) 
as 
    ( select  so.object_id as Base_Object_Id 
        , so.schema_id as Base_Cchema_Id 
        , so.name as Base_Object_Name 
        , so.type_desc as Base_Object_Type
        , so.object_id as object_id 
        , so.schema_id as Schema_Id 
        , so.name 
        , so.type_desc 
        , 0 as Level 
        , convert ( nvarchar ( 1000 ) , N'/' + so.name ) as Obj_Path 
    from sys.objects so 
        left join sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed on ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
        left join sys.objects rso on rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
    where --rso.type is null 
         so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF' ) 

    union all 

    select   cp.Base_Object_Id as Base_Object_Id 
        , cp.Base_Cchema_Id 
        , cp.Base_Object_Name 
        , cp.Base_Object_Type
        , so.object_id as object_id 
        , so.schema_id as ID_Schema 
        , so.name 
        , so.type_desc 
        , Level + 1 as Level 
        , convert ( nvarchar ( 1000 ) , cp.Obj_Path + N'/' + so.name ) as Obj_Path 
    from sys.objects so 
        inner join sys.sql_expression_dependencies ed on ed.referenced_id = so.object_id 
        inner join sys.objects rso on rso.object_id = ed.referencing_id 
        inner join ObjectHierarchy as cp on rso.object_id = cp.object_id and rso.object_id <> so.object_id 
    where so.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U') 
        and ( rso.type is null or rso.type in ( 'P', 'V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF', 'U' ) ) 
        and cp.Obj_Path not like '%/' + so.name + '/%' )   -- prevent cycles n hierarcy


select  DISTINCT  Base_Object_Name 
    , Base_Object_Type
    , REPLICATE ( '   ' , Level ) + Name as Indented_Name 
    , SCHEMA_NAME ( Schema_Id ) + '.' + Name as object_id 
    , Type_Desc as Object_Type 
    , Level 
    , Obj_Path 
from ObjectHierarchy as p 
WHERE BASE_OBJECT_TYPE = 'VIEW'
order by Obj_Path;


-------  Logic shows how a table is populated

SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id))
FROM   sys.sql_dependencies
WHERE  referenced_major_id = OBJECT_ID((SELECT DISTINCT object_id  FROM ObjectHierarchy))
       AND is_updated = 1
GROUP  BY object_id
```

Comment: I would suggest you read this. Nested views are evil. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/performance-sql-server/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: For the question at hand it would be ugly to do that kind of a search. I would suggest not even trying to do that. What would happen if more than one procedure can insert into a given table?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry the above example isnt clear. I should have order it better. Its saying the view is the employee detail and it pulls on two tables the dbo.employee and dbo.salary. In the above example it isnt pulling on a separate view. Your point is valid though as there is such a view we use but its combining metrics so it would be quite difficult to replicate without pulling on another view.

Comment: Yes thinking about it there would be cases where a table could be populated by a different store procedure depending on the day. It is something i didnt think about. I could possible just do a join and add a column showing the procedure which would populate the table when referenced.

Comment: how do you track dynamic sql manipulations of tables

Comment: This sounds like fool's errand. also, I'm not sure dependencies are always correct either, if you for example create procedure before you create the table

Comment: I have tested quite a few of the dependencies and they do all seem to work as i would expect. It is picking up the source of all the info. On the dynamic sql manipulation i am mainly just concerned with ones which are populated by store procedures. It would be more of a general guide to how the database flows than a rulebook.

Comment: Sure, i get it, but what if stored procedure does: exec('insert into yourtable select 1') :)

Comment: Its a valid point and is one i have thought about. My plan was to review and exclude any procedure which may act like this. Again i know its not a great solution but currently it is difficult for some users to understand how the data flows and what is reliant on each other. Is there a different approach i should maybe be checking into which could create this guide for users.